# Why this action doesn't result in a file being downloaded? How to do that?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a program in `ASP.NET MVC3...` How may I export a `.xml` file, dynamically generated, to be downloaded?

I call the Export routine through a button in my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
… 
        <input type="submit" value="Export to XML" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: green;" asp-action="Export" asp-controller="Manage" />
… 
    </div>
```

With this button, I want to generate a XML file and to open a download Save As dialog to download it to the local computer…

Then I have the following Export action in the ManageController:

```
public IActionResult Export(IFormCollection form)
{
    … gathers form info and gets the table to be exported: oTable
    // export to .xml here!
    ExportXMLModel e = new ExportXMLModel();

    return (e.DoExportXML(oTable)); // Doesnt export...
    // sorry for the clumsy code…, but I'll write it better afterwards.
}
```

The DoExportXML is defined here (here I create a MemoryStream…):

```
public class ExportXMLModel
{
   public ActionResult DoExportXML(List<itemType> ol)
   {
       XMLDocType XMLdoc = new XMLDocType();

       … fills the XMLdoc object … 

       MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

       XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLDocType));

       TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);

       xml.Serialize(writer, XMLdoc);

       FileResult file = new FileResult(memoryStream.ToArray(), "text/xml", "myXmlFile.xml");

       writer.Close();

       return file;
   }
}
```

And the FileResult class is then defined:

```
public class FileResult : ActionResult
{
    public String ContentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileBytes { get; set; }
    public String SourceFilename { get; set; }

    public FileResult(byte[] sourceStream, String contentType, String sourceFilename)
    {
         FileBytes = sourceStream;
         SourceFilename = sourceFilename;
         ContentType = contentType;
    }
}
```

This doesn't result in a file being downloaded…

How may I produce such a response? With `ASP.NET MVC` or with jQuery?

Thank you very much for any answer.

Comment: You should not be building your own FileResult, you should use the [built-in one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fileresult?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET Framework [Controller.File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.file?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) and .NET Core [ControllerBase.File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-3.1) provide abstractions on several `FileResult` methods. Both can take a byte array or a stream to return, and allow you to define content-types and filenames.

Just a few modifications would make your code work fine. You don't need the `FileResult` class (MS has already done the heavy lifting on that). Modify the `ExportXMLModel.DoExportXML` to return a byte array (which you're converting the stream to, but then passing it to your custom `FileResult`).

Then your controller action looks like this:

```cs
public IActionResult Export(IFormCollection form)
{
    … gathers form info and gets the table to be exported: oTable
    // export to .xml here!
    ExportXMLModel e = new ExportXMLModel();

    return File(e.DoExportXML(oTable), "text/xml", "myXmlFile.xml");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nathan. Your answer was the solution!